# Intellij doesn't run in Debug mode - file not found "junit.properties"

Tags: java, maven, exception, intellij-idea, junit

I have a Java Library that has a test suite. I can run the tests correctly both in maven and in IntelliJ, but when I try to run them in debug mode, it throws an exception  `C:\Users\drotman\junit.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)`. The function that it stops at is `private native void open0(String name) throws FileNotFoundException;` from the `FileInputStream.java`

I searched far and wide and couldn't find any information about what that file is and why it is only needed in debug mode.

I tried re-installing intelliJ and both in Community and Ultimate, and the same problem persists. Also, I tried to change the version of Junit to no avail.

Comment: which build framework do you use? do you have any third-party plugins enabled? also, sounds like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-289953, check the discussion in comments